# Replace active flag to the next item after filtering in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a response from an api that I need to filter. After filtering I need to set the active item. After the filtering there is case that no active item is set to true because the initial active has been filtered. I want to enable the next possible active element.

```
// This object array is always sorted with the same length. 
const data = [ 
  { id: 241, name: "item 1",count: 0, active: false},
  { id: 221, name: "item 2",count: 4, active: true},
  { id: 343, name: "item 3",count: 0, active: false},
  { id: 129, name: "item 3",count: 0, active: false}
]

const dataActive = data.find( el=> el.active === true);
const filtered = data.filter(el => el.count < 3);
```

How can I change the active flag of item 3 in the filtered array of objects to true?

So the output of filtered to be:

```
  { id: 241, name: "item 1",count: 0, active: false},
  { id: 343, name: "item 3",count: 0, active: true},
  { id: 129, name: "item 3",count: 0, active: false}
```

Comment: add an `id` prop that you can use to find it easily

Comment: Even with id I have the same problem. The object is always sorted

Comment: I want to make active the next element of the object where count > 4 . In my case the Item 3

Comment: What if there are multiple elements with `count > 4`?

Comment: Any of them. After filtering the next Item in sequence. In this case is item 3

Comment: It has to go to next next active depending on the active flag from original object. Sequencially

Comment: Sequentially based on the string in `name`?  There is no clear-cut sequence of strings.  Are they guaranteed to have the format `"name {nbr}"`?

Comment: @stavgian : If either of 2 answers did solve your problem, you may accept that ;)

Answer (score 1):

If mutating source data wouldn't bother you, you may do necessary side-effects from within `filter()`:

```js
const data = [ 
        { id: 241, name: "item 1",count: 0, active: false},
        { id: 221, name: "item 2",count: 4, active: true},
        { id: 343, name: "item 3",count: 0, active: false},
        { id: 129, name: "item 3",count: 0, active: false}
      ],
      
      filtered = data.filter(item => 
        item.count < 3 ? 
        (shiftFlag ? (item.active = true, shiftFlag = false, true) : true) :
        (item.active ? (shiftFlag = true, item.active = false, false) : false),
        shiftFlag=false)
        
console.log(filtered)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

And, of course, above will not shift active flag to the *next* item if active item will go the last in the array and it must have been filtered out.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work but there may be better ways to do it.

```
const data = [ 
  { id: 241, name: "item 1",count: 0, active: false},
  { id: 221, name: "item 2",count: 4, active: true},
  { id: 343, name: "item 3",count: 0, active: false},
  { id: 129, name: "item 3",count: 0, active: false}
]

const dataActive = data.find( el=> el.active === true);
let isFound = false;
//you have to consider the edge cases if you take this process in consideration
const newMappedData = data.map(el => {
    if(el.active && !isFound){
      isFound = true;
      data[data.indexOf(el) + 1].active = true;
      //any kind of identifier that says the data is to be filtered out
      return false;
  }
  return el; 
});

const filtered = newMappedData.filter(el => el != false)
console.log(filtered)
```